# Soundcloud - Problems getting access token - get message invalid_client

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth-2.0, soundcloud

I've registered an app on soundcloud.com I'm trying to login with oauth 2 and php using curl I can what seems to login ok but when go to exchange the token for the access code I get the follow error: {"error":"invalid_client"}

I'm posting using curl

```
if(isset($_GET['code'])){

$url = 'https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token';
$fields = array(
                    'client_id'=>urlencode($clientID),
                    'clientSecret'=>urlencode($clientSecret),
                    'grant_type'=>urlencode('authorization_code'),
                    'redirect_uri'=>urlencode($redirectUrl),
                    'code'=>urlencode($_GET['code'])
            );
$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);

$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
if ($data === FALSE) {
    die("Curl failed: " . curl_error($ch));
} else {
    print_r($data);
}

}
```

I'm hoping someone on here can you point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I've fixed it I had the clientSecret incorrectly it needed to be client_secret in the array.